# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 for IPHONE camera sometime it work sometime dont

Tags: iphone

i have used 2  textfeild and this i am using this () to shoot pic

```
- (IBAction)shoot:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@" START SHOOTING");
    UIImagePickerController * picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker1.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker1 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    NSLog(@" STOP SHOOTING");
    [picker1 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

i am getting this error wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003  while shooting 
sometime its working soemtime dont

Comment: I get this one occasionally too... doesn't seem to be harmful or related to anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

got it just restart device

Answer (score 0):

every time you type "alloc", you make yourself responsible for a corresponding "release" or "autorelease".

The easiest fix will be:

```
UIImagePickerController * picker1 = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Try to read something about iphone memory management, before writing an app. It will save you headaches.